# iAP buy button with price tier text

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

How do I add the price of the iAP on the button as text?

I don't mean like this:

```
upgradeButton.setTitle("19", forState: .Normal)
```

But if I change price in iTunes Connect, it also changes on the button. I have tried something like this:

```
var product_id: NSString?;
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        product_id = "com.iia.cuz.PRO";

        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)

        let response = SKProductsResponse()
        let validProduct: SKProduct = response.products[0]
        if (validProduct.productIdentifier == self.product_id) {
            upgradeButton.setTitle(validProduct.price.description, forState: .Normal)
        }
    }
```

When I try this, it crashes on the line:
`let validProduct: SKProduct = response.products[0]`

I have imported `StoreKit` and added `SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver` in the class.

Any suggestions?

Comment: adding TransactionObserver to the viewDidLoad of ViewController is very bad practise.consider it replacing at AppDelegate

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an [`SKProductsRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProductsRequest/):

- Initialise it with the relevant product identifier(s)
- set the `delegate`
- `start`it
- in the delegate, implement `productsRequest:didReceiveResponse:` which will receive the product(s) matching the identifier(s). You can then retrieve the price from the product

Note that you should use a number formatter in currency style, using the provided locale, to format the price correctly. See the example in the description of the [`price`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProduct_Reference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKProduct/price) property of `SKProduct` (only visible when in "Objective-C" mode, but easy to translate to Swift).

Comment: This is not a free code-writing service. If you need someone to write code for you, please hire someone to do so. The above instructions should be more than enough to enable you to write the relevant code.

Comment: You are not very helpfull. Please, don't bother starting a discussion if you are not going to contribute. K. Bye.